# Why is there a special pronunciation of 论 just for 论语?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, history

The character 论 has pinyin lùn for all uses except in 论语 where it is 
lún.  Is there some known historical reason for this change in pronunciation?

Comment: I am not giving an answer because I only know about a Cantonese practice (I don't know if Mandarin follows the same habit or not. ) In Cantonese speech, tone 2 changes for characters are very common. For example, the standard Jyutping of 李 is / lei5 /, but it is often read with a tone 2 change and become / lei5*2 /. May be 论 can be read in a tone 2 changes when it is emphasized in Mandarin.

Comment: When [论](http://www.zdic.net/z/24/js/8BBA.htm) pronounced as lún it's same with `伦` (`条理`) in the ancient time. And 论语 is a book about `条理` (or `人伦`), that might be the reason.

Comment: [伦敦](https://youdao.com/w/伦敦) (lún dūn) = London, seems to be another example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit of research, I've come across a possible explanation.

According to [this source](http://www.yywzb.com.cn/more.asp?infoid=5338) from the 语言文字报 Journal of Language and Writing (not sure the English name is correct) it appears that the character 论 was archaically used with the meaning of **to edit, to compile** as in the  word **论纂 lun2 zuan3**, same as 编撰 bian1 zhuan4. 
The reference given is the scholar [Lu Xun](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%B2%81%E8%BF%85) who in his [teaching materials](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B1%89%E6%96%87%E5%AD%A6%E5%8F%B2%E7%BA%B2%E8%A6%81) for a class at Xiamen University, talked about the Analects:

> ﹝ 孔子 ﹞ 既卒 [...]， 门人又相与辑其言行而**论纂**之， 谓之《论语》
>
> [After Confucius' death], the disciples revised each other's notes [of the master's teachings] and compiled a book, which they called "Edited words".

So if we take this for good, the 论 lún in 论语 is a legacy of the archaic 论纂 (to edit, to compile) as Confucius' disciples *compiled* his teachings into a volume that later became known as 论语, which literally means “edited words".

Comment: Ah.  And so the first westerners to latinize the name of the compilation used "analect" to mean selected.

Comment: That's correct, "analects" means precisely that. A compilation of selected speeches.